# What is the average number of hashes it takes to mine bitcoins?

Tags: hash, difficulty, hashpower

I'm just curious about this. I'm not sure if the length of zeros in the hash result is directly proportional to the probability, or how to calculate this.

Comment: Yes, the length of zeros in the required hash result is directly proportional to the probability of finding a matching hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Average hashing power of network per second between the last difficulty adjustment and the difficulty adjustment that came before it) * 600

or (2^32 * difficulty)

Comment: Where can I find out this information?

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty

Answer (score 0):

As relative Answer in terms of Coins per day:

```
                                                          A      B
coins = reward / (difficulty * 4294967296 / hashsPerSec / 3600 / 24)
```

> A is the number of seconds in an hour
>
> B is the number hours in a day

Source: [bitcointalk.org - Formula to calculate litecoins generated per day by hashrate](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=123966.msg1332328#msg1332328)